# Excel VBA index out of bounds while using Sheets.delete

Tags: excel, vba, indexing

After a few iterations of the following code I always get the error that the index was out of bounds.

```
    For i = myworksheet.index To Worksheets.count
        Sheets(i).delete
    Next i
```

Comment: You need to loop backwards otherwise you will be trying to delete the e.g. 4th sheet of a file containing 3 sheets. Or use sheet names. Or use FaneDuru's approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't delete sheets this way.

Consider what you're asking it to do. Let's say you have 5 worksheets- Sheet1, Sheet2.. Sheet 5.

[image]

Let's say `myworksheet` is Sheet3 (`i=3`).

When the loop starts, `i` is 3.

`Sheet3` is deleted.

[image]

The loop restarts and `i` is now 4.

However, there are now only 4 worksheets. So `Sheet5` (`i=4`) is deleted.

[image]

The loop restarts and `i` is now 5.

However, there are now only 3 worksheets. There is no worksheet with index of 5 to delete.

---

One (of many) ways to achieve your goal is to do the following:

```
i = myworksheet.Index

Do Until Worksheets.Count = i - 1
    Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Delete
Loop
```

One thing to point out with this.. in your code, you appear to be deleting your start sheet `myworksheet`. Because of this, the `Do Until...` loop I've created  finishes at i-1 to stop ***after*** `myworksheet` is deleted. If you didn't want this to happen, remove the `- 1`. If you did want this to happen, you need to be aware that it will error if the index of `myworksheet` is 1 - as all workbooks must contain at least 1 worksheet.

Comment: basically I realized my stupidity as soon as I had the first glance at the very first table you posted...thank you for resolving my mental block...

Answer (score 1):

Try the next way, please. In your code, after sheets deleting, the reference not make sense for `i` bigger then existing maximum (remained) one:

```
Sub deleteSheets()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Index > sh.Index Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         ws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Or looping backwards, as @SJR suggested:

```
Sub deleteSheetsBis()
Dim myworksheet As Worksheet, i As Long
Set myworksheet = ActiveSheet
For i = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count To myworksheet.Index Step -1
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      Sheets(i).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next i
End Sub
```